# Remove extra space in Talend outputexcelfile

Tags: talend

In Talend:I am trying to remove the extra space in Texceloutputfile. Attached the example in below image.

[image]

Comment: Talend would not add an extra character to your output. Are you sure that your input data is not containing this extra-space ?

Answer (score 0):

you might have special charater \t in your string.
try to remove \t using replace function in **tmap** or use **tReplace** component to remove \t.